# Refresh Page In wpf

Tags: wpf, window, refresh

1. How to close or cancel the pop up window in Button click.?
2. When i update the data in pop up window, the same time how to refresh the datagrid in main page.?

Thanking u

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781250/wpf-page-refresh. Perhaps as the result of a messed up attempt at posting the original.

Answer (score 0):

1. IsOpen property of popup should be set false.
2. Use Binding.