# WPF Page refresh

Tags: wpf, window, refresh

1.How to close or cancel the pop up window in Button click.?

2. When i update the data in pop up window, the same time how to refresh the datagrid in main page.?

Answer (score 0):

Close a popup by optionally setting DialogResult to true/false and then calling Close().
You can set the IsDefault or IsCancel property on a button to automatically set the result & close.

You need to provide more information for your datagrid question.